# prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) Not firing in Xcode 8.1 swift 3 ios 10

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a tabbed view controller that is associated with two view controllers.

I need to pass an array from the first View Controller to the Second View controller.

In Order to do this I have the following code in my first VC:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "AddItem"
        {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController
            {
                destinationVC.toDoList = toDoList
            }
        }
    }
```

However this is not getting fired when I switch two the second VC using the tab button.

Any ideas as to why this is not getting fired?

This is how my main storyboard looks like:
[Main Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llGYD.png)

Comment: As per your storyboard you are using tabBarController no need for segue

Comment: you are not performing segue anywhere using tabbarcontroller with its child so that method is never called

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prepare for segue not being called with tabbarcontroller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194514/prepare-for-segue-not-being-called-with-tabbarcontroller)

Comment: @Sanket Rajgarhia, i think this can help you :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194514/prepare-for-segue-not-being-called-with-tabbarcontroller/41194626#41194626

Answer (score 0):

You cannot transfer objects between tab views through segue because the VC is not actually making a direct segue connection rather you can do it with a delegate or a notificationCenter post and observe to transfer

Answer (score 0):

You have to put that segue code in Tabbar controller class. You shouldn't put that thing in firstVC. Because there is no segue is going on from first VC to Second VC.